# Openshift: ssh auth failure after deleting and recreating an app with the same name

Tags: ssh, openshift

I'm wondering if anybody had the problem or maybe can explain to me why when I delete and create an app again (with the same name) on Openshift I can't git push or ssh at all.

Before you ask, my ssh rsa key were working before and nothing changed. For that matter, it works when I create an app with a different name.

```
$ ls -la ~/.ssh/
drwx------  2 guillaume guillaume  1024 Mar 22 12:25 .
drwx------ 47 guillaume guillaume 11264 Mar 22 12:34 ..
-rw-------  1 guillaume guillaume  3243 Sep 10  2015 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 guillaume guillaume   753 Sep 10  2015 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 guillaume guillaume   852 Mar 22 12:33 known_hosts
```

```
$ ssh -vvv -t 56f0c0f189f5cf10e00000c2@<app-name>-<domain-name> -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 
OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "seatbug-simplicity.rhcloud.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to seatbug-simplicity.rhcloud.com [52.21.123.126] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/guillaume/.ssh/id_rsa.pub type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/guillaume/.ssh/id_rsa.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to seatbug-simplicity.rhcloud.com:22 as '56f0c0f189f5cf10e00000c2'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/guillaume/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/guillaume/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from seatbug-simplicity.rhcloud.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<3072<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1502/3072
debug3: send packet: type 32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 33
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:FeJCkIUL7D41FMGNtM5NYM4XoboxZGYEqH0WcAmOX+I
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/guillaume/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/guillaume/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from seatbug-simplicity.rhcloud.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/guillaume/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/guillaume/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 52.21.123.126
debug1: Host 'seatbug-simplicity.rhcloud.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/guillaume/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 1528/3072
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/guillaume/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (0x55d0825e07f0), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/guillaume/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
[guillaume@gibjiz seatbug]$ 
[guillaume@gibjiz seatbug]$ ssh -vvv -t 56f0c0f189f5cf10e00000c2@seatbug-simplicity.rhcloud.com -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 
OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "seatbug-simplicity.rhcloud.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to seatbug-simplicity.rhcloud.com [52.21.123.126] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/guillaume/.ssh/id_rsa.pub type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/guillaume/.ssh/id_rsa.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to seatbug-simplicity.rhcloud.com:22 as '56f0c0f189f5cf10e00000c2'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/guillaume/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/guillaume/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from seatbug-simplicity.rhcloud.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<3072<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1469/3072
debug3: send packet: type 32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 33
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:FeJCkIUL7D41FMGNtM5NYM4XoboxZGYEqH0WcAmOX+I
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/guillaume/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/guillaume/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from seatbug-simplicity.rhcloud.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/guillaume/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/guillaume/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 52.21.123.126
debug1: Host 'seatbug-simplicity.rhcloud.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/guillaume/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 1550/3072
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/guillaume/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (0x55febc2867f0), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/guillaume/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

and

```
$ cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config
Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Thank you for the time you pased reading/thinking/answering :D

Answer (score 1):

You should allow some time for the OpenShift brokers to update and the app deletion info to propagate before you create another app with the same name.

You can also try to move you `known_hosts` file elsewhere, and then try again, just to check if the `StrictHostKeyChecking no` is working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

 I tried to move the `known_hosts` file but nothing change except that another one was created upon attempt to connect.

Other than that, wouldn't a night (ok let's say 5 hours) be long enough for the broker to update ?

Comment: Are you updating the hash before the app name? i.e. 56f0c0f189f5cf10e00000c2@<app-name>-<domain-name>

Comment: Also, I created, cloned, deleted, created, cloned an app with the same name, and it works fine to me

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong then but this is weird since I tried many times and even when I was trying to create an app with the rhc, it was not even finishing the process(the app was visible on the webconsole but the actual app was not working, no "default kinda hello world"). And yes, I was copying the git repo link from either the rhc or the web console. Anyway, this is not a big deal but it got me really frustrated and I would have liked to understand :)

Comment: @Yormi note that the git clone url and the ssh url are slightly different, with the git stuff at the end

Comment: Yep I know :) It didn't help me though... I'm still clueless about what happened since it seems to work just fine for you.